# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate only update fields if there is no value or it's null otherwise leave as it is

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I update only if there is no value on fields?

```js
//...just a sample code snippet

const {name, email, phone} = data;
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
   { email},
   { name // only update if not exists or null or no value },
   {new:true,upsert: true}
)

console.log(user}

//...code
```

This is just an example. I just want to know if we can update the name field value only if there is no value else leave the field value as it is.

Comment: You can use [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to check if the field present in the document or not. Is it what you want?

Comment: I believe `{ name : null }` will match even if the field doesn't exist

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh you'll get: `error - unhandledRejection: Error: Can't use $exist with String` because String Schema Type doesn't seem to support the: `$exist` logical operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
const {name, email, phone} = data;
let user = await User.findOne({ email}, { name });

if(!user) {
  user = new User({name, email, phone});
} else {
  if(!user['name')) {
    user['name'] = name;
  }
}
await user.save();
```